# Main never runs? Bubble sort & Selections sort

Tags: c++, xcode

I can't seem to have any output and unfortunately my teacher can't help me. I'm using xcode and previously we have had to change quite a few things to get programs to work and this time I cannot get anything to happen. At first I had just a bubble sort with six numbers and got it to run, but we then added a selection sort and instead of having numbers, they are read in from a txt file.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void bubble(string filename);
void selectionSort(string filename);


const int SIZE = 100000;
int values[SIZE];

// Main
int main()
{
    cout << "Beginning set of our bubble sorts. Please stand by... " << endl;
    bubble("inOrder.txt");
    bubble("revOrder.txt");
    bubble("ranOrder1.txt");
    bubble("ranOrder2.txt");
    cout << "Finished with four bubble sorts. " << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

// Functions

void bubble(string filename)
{
    unsigned long int passCount = 0, compCount = 0, swapCount = 0;

    int temp;
    bool swap;

    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());

    for ( int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        fin >> values[j];


    do
    {   passCount++;
        swap = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < (SIZE -1); count++)
        {
            compCount++;
            if(values[count] > values[count + 1])
            {
                swapCount++;
                temp = values[count];
                values[count] = values[count + 1];
                values[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }


    } while (swap);
    string outputName = "Bubble" + filename;

    ofstream fout(outputName.c_str());

    for ( int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        fout << values[j] << endl;
    cout << "The number of passes is: " << passCount << endl;
    cout << "The number of comparious is:" << compCount << endl;
    cout << "The number of swaps is: " << swapCount << endl;

}


// Selection



void selectionSort(int array[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (SIZE - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = values[startScan];
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (values[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = values[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        values[minIndex = array[startScan]];
        values[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the word 'array' in the sorts to values  but it didn't work. And before changing the parameters of the function (and changing the other parts mentioned above) we only had 'string filename' and it worked fine. A lot of things are working for the teacher, but she is using Visual Express. I'm downloading that now but the school internet is extremely slow so I'm trying to work with what I have.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Also, the most of the code was done as a class, but not everything worked the same in xcode. As homework I had to add the selection sort and I'm struggling a bit.

**EDIT**
I'm sorry, I meant I need the output to be files. We had a seperate .cpp file to generate the number needed for the program to do the sorts.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

const int maxSize = 100000;

int main()
{

    ofstream fout1("inOrder.txt");
    ofstream fout2("revOrder.txt");
    ofstream fout3("ranOrder.txt");
    ofstream fout4("ranOrder.txt");

    cout << "Starting to create 4 output files. . ." << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= maxSize; i++)
    {
        fout1 << i << endl;
        fout2 << maxSize - i  + 1 << endl;
        fout3 << rand() << endl;
        fout4 << rand() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Finished creating 4 output files . . ." << endl;

    system( "PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

All of this code was written by my instructor. For Xcode do I just add the file to the same folder as the main program?

Comment: I'd start by making sure your files are opened correctly. The Xcode run-from directory isn't as trivial as it seems. It is usually off in some temp build folder. You can change it if you determine this is the problem (unless you knew this and already addressed it in your schema-config).

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? I'd have expected to get a few compiler errors, telling me about the bogus name `array` (which you say you fixed), a missing `]`, and perhaps `system` since you don't include `<cstdlib>`. Note that `system("PAUSE")` probably won't do anything on a non-Microsoft platform, but is only needed if you're using an evil IDE that closes the program's output window as soon as it exits.

Comment: Why not simply debugging the problem by 1. adding some proper error-handling and 2. single-stepping through the code?

Comment: what is the environment? maybe const int SIZE = 100000;
int values[SIZE]; is just to much?

Comment: Are you sure it compiles? Listing you provided has errors (missing ']' in `array[minIndex = array[startScan];`) and undeclared identifier ('array' in function `bubble`).

Comment: I changed 'array' again, added the }, and I had no idea that system would do anything in Xcode! Visual Express actually closes the output window as it exits. It's the only compiler my teacher uses.

Comment: Also, @piotruś I don't know what you mean by what is the enviorment. That size was set by my instructor because she wants that amount of number sorted (if I'm understanding your question). I'm going to continue going through to get it to work

Comment: do you have any output from main? Is "Starting to create 4 output files. . ." printed out?

Comment: I gotten the program to start but I can't get the sort file to quite work. I'll google some stuff about it. @piotruś Yes, but then nothing else happened though I may have been impatient. My instructor did say it could take a while for everything

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this issue with opening files using Xcode as well. I've found that if you don't specify a full file path for the txt file you are trying to open, Xcode will check the project folder as expected. The thing is that you have to have added the txt file to the Xcode project, not just drop it in the project folder in Finder.

In Xcode, go to to FILE > Add Files and add the txt files you are trying to open to the project.